# align pandas series per alphabetical order

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas series such as follow:

```
                                        indicator_name    
1                                 6-Month Bill Auction
2                                  7-Year Note Auction
3                        ADP Nonfarm Employment Change
4                                        All Car Sales
5                                      All Truck Sales
6                           API Weekly Crude Oil Stock
7                   API Weekly Cushing Crude Oil Stock
8                        API Weekly Distillates Stocks
9                            API Weekly Gasoline Stock
10                       Average Hourly Earnings (MoM)
11                                Average Weekly Hours

...
```

and

```
                                    indicator_name
1                            ADP Employment Change
2                      Advance Goods Trade Balance
3                             Advance Retail Sales
4                      Average Hourly Earnings MoM
5                      Average Hourly Earnings YoY
6               Average Weekly Hours All Employees
7                      Avg Hourly Earning MOM Prod
8                      Avg Hourly Earning YOY Prod
9                      Avg Weekly Hours Production
```

I would like to combine them so that they align alphabetically in the following way:

```
1   6-Month Bill Auction                 null
2   7-Year Note Auction                  null
3   null                                 ADP Employment Change
4   ADP Nonfarm Employment Change        Advance Goods Trade Balance
5   null                                 Advance Retail Sales
6   All Car Sales                        null
7   All Truck Sales                      null
8   API Weekly Crude Oil Stock           null
9   API Weekly Cushing Crude Oil Stock   null
10  API Weekly Distillates Stocks        null
11  API Weekly Gasoline Stock            null
12  Average Hourly Earnings (MoM)        Average Hourly Earnings MoM
13  null                                 Average Hourly Earnings YoY
14  Average Weekly Hours                 Average Weekly Hours All Employees
15  null                                 Avg Hourly Earning MOM Prod
16  null                                 Avg Hourly Earning YOY Prod
17  null                                 Avg Weekly Hours Production
```

Any suggestion on how that could be done swiftly?
Thx!

Comment: @zaq I think the idea would be to align so that is it alphabetically ordered first  from left to right and then from top to bottom. In such case it is true that "ADP Nonfarm Employment change) should go down 1 row. I would say what i would expect is an idea/code snippet that does more or less what i describe above, and that i can refine later on to cater ore specifically to what i am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have one column dataframes.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'indicator_name':[
                        '6-Month Bill Auction',
                                  '7-Year Note Auction',
                        'ADP Nonfarm Employment Change',
                                        'All Car Sales',
                                      'All Truck Sales',
                           'API Weekly Crude Oil Stock',
                   'API Weekly Cushing Crude Oil Stock',
                        'API Weekly Distillates Stocks',
                            'API Weekly Gasoline Stock',
                       'Average Hourly Earnings (MoM)',
                                'Average Weekly Hours']})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'indicator_name':[
                        'ADP Employment Change',
                      'Advance Goods Trade Balance',
                             'Advance Retail Sales',
                      'Average Hourly Earnings MoM',
                      'Average Hourly Earnings YoY',
               'Average Weekly Hours All Employees',
                      'Avg Hourly Earning MOM Prod',
                      'Avg Hourly Earning YOY Prod',
                      'Avg Weekly Hours Production']})

df.set_index('indicator_name', drop=False, inplace=True)
df1.set_index('indicator_name', drop=False, inplace=True)
df1.columns = ['indicator_name2']
pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

output

```
     indicator_name                     indicator_name2
0                 6-Month Bill Auction                                 NaN
1                  7-Year Note Auction                                 NaN
2                                  NaN               ADP Employment Change
3        ADP Nonfarm Employment Change                                 NaN
4           API Weekly Crude Oil Stock                                 NaN
5   API Weekly Cushing Crude Oil Stock                                 NaN
6        API Weekly Distillates Stocks                                 NaN
7            API Weekly Gasoline Stock                                 NaN
8                                  NaN         Advance Goods Trade Balance
9                                  NaN                Advance Retail Sales
10                       All Car Sales                                 NaN
11                     All Truck Sales                                 NaN
12       Average Hourly Earnings (MoM)                                 NaN
13                                 NaN         Average Hourly Earnings MoM
14                                 NaN         Average Hourly Earnings YoY
15                Average Weekly Hours                                 NaN
16                                 NaN  Average Weekly Hours All Employees
17                                 NaN         Avg Hourly Earning MOM Prod
18                                 NaN         Avg Hourly Earning YOY Prod
19                                 NaN         Avg Weekly Hours Production
```

Comment: thx - they actually were originally not Series but Dataframes - so i tried: `merged_data = pd.merge(indicators_list, indicators_ft_list, how='outer', on=['indicator_name'])` and `merged_data = pd.merge(indicators_list, indicators_ft_list, how='outer')` but in both case the indicator_name column values are merged into 1 single column and not 2 next to each other. Any insight on that?

Comment: Again, Thx a lot. Could you provide a solution how to do when the 2 are actually Dataframes and not Series? Thx!

Comment: no it doesnt seems to work: the newly created "indicator_name2" column have only NaN values. Also the index created from the values of both DFs are in such format `(ADP Employment Survey k,)` (ie with parenthesis and comma) which might be the reason for it not to work? i dont know..

Comment: Ok, I changed the answer again. This will only have one non-null item per row unless the strings are exactly equal.

Comment: I dont know why, but when implementing your code, the second column is still NaN. When i print the second dataframe alone i can see it is correctly showing values of the column "indicators_name" in both the index and the vaues column

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer to show my exact code with data load. Are there any rules about two non matching items appearing in the same row or should each row have one missing value?